# Build the Opencv-2.4.5 For CARMA Issue

Tags: opencv, build, cmake

I have successfully Done Cmake with following option.

```
$cmake -DGCC_COMPILER_VERSION="4.5" -DSOFTFP=ON -DUSE_NEON=ON -DCMAKE_SKIP_RPATH=ON -DCUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/cuda-5.0 -DCUDA_ARCH_BIN="2.1(2.0)" -DCUDA_ARCH_PTX="" -DWITH_CUDA=ON -DWITH_CUBLAS=ON -DWITH_TBB=ON -DBUILD_opencv_python=OFF -DBUILD_TBB=ON -DBUILD_ZLIB=ON -DBUILD_TIFF=ON -DBUILD_JASPER=ON -DBUILD_JPEG=ON -DBUILD_PNG=ON -DBUILD_OPENEXR=ON -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/intecore/carma/opencv-2.4.5/platforms/linux/arm-gnueabi.toolchain.cmake /home/intecore/carma/opencv-2.4.5
```

But problem is occurred in make after 23% that is

```
[ 23%] Building NVCC (Device) object modules/core/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/./cuda_compile_generated_matrix_operations.cu.o
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mthumb’
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mfpu=neon’
CMake Error at cuda_compile_generated_matrix_operations.cu.o.cmake:198 (message):
  Error generating
  /home/intecore/carma/opencv-2.4.5/platforms/linux/carma_build/modules/core/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/./cuda_compile_generated_matrix_operations.cu.o


make[2]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/./cuda_compile_generated_matrix_operations.cu.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I am not understanding where I made made mistake please give me solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are using old version of CMake.

Cross-compilation with CUDA requires at least 2.8.10 CMake version. It is not available in Ubuntu repository.

Please download the latest CMake from their website: http://www.cmake.org/cmake/resources/software.html

Here is instruction for CARMA compilation:
http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/CARMA_platform_compilation_and_testing

## GTK Support

OpenCV can be compiled with UI support using GTK back-end.

- Install GTK on target device.

  apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
- Install GTK on host (for required header files).

  apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
- Copy `/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi` and `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi` folders from target to host to the same location.
- In addition to the two directories above, copy all files from `/usr/lib` on target to the `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi` on host machine.
- Install `pkg-config-arm-linux-gnueabi` package on host.

  apt-get install pkg-config-arm-linux-gnueabi
- Add next parameters to cmake command line:

  -DPKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-pkg-config -DWITH_GTK=ON

Comment: I am using cmake version 2.8.7 is it creating problem?

Comment: Yes, you need at least 2.8.10.

Comment: yes i changed it to ver 2.8.10.1; But I am getting new errors:                                                         cicc: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
CMake Error at cuda_compile_generated_matrix_operations.cu.o.cmake:264 (message):
  Error generating file
  /home/intecoretech/carma/opencv-2.4.5/platforms/linux/build_carma/modules/core/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/./cuda_compile_generated_matrix_operations.cu.o

Comment: Did you follow this instruction: http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/CARMA_platform_compilation_and_testing?

Comment: Yes, I am following the same instructions in the link. Now the OpenCV could be built for CARMA with Cmake ver 2.8.11.2. Now, for enabling GUI on CARMA, we are trying to re-build OpenCV with -DWITH_GTK=ON. I have already installed gtk+2.0 in my machine. But, when I run CMake 2.8.11.2, it reports GTK not found. But when i tried with cmake 2.8.7 on the same environment, GTK could be found. Any idea ?