# Building CUDA 5.5 with OpenCV 2.4.8

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012, cuda

I am trying to build CUDA 5.5 with OpenCV 2.4.8 to make an x86 application.

I am running on Windows 8.1 64 bit using VS2012 C++/cli and am having crazy troubles getting my app to build.

I downloaded CUDA 5.5 Windows 8.1 64 bit for Desktop (it will not let me install 32 bit anyway).

Then, I did the following:

1) load CMake and set the target machine as Visual Studio 11 (not Win 64)

2) turn off CUDA BUILD ATTACH v RULE

3) configure and generate

4) load the ALL_BUILD project in Visual Studio specifying Win32

During the build, I get the following error:

`6>CMakeFiles\cuda_compile.dir\__\dynamicuda\src\cuda\Debug\cuda_compile_generated_matrix_operations.cu.obj : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'`

`Build FAILED.`

It is my understanding that you have to compile everything to your target architecture and since mine is Win32 (because of other libraries), it would seem that I have to build OpenCV to that architecture as well.

What am I doing wrong?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Apparently, this issue can be due to an old version of CMake. Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17993599/build-the-opencv-2-4-5-for-carma-issue

Comment: Thanks for your note.  I am using CMake 2.8.11.2 which is only a few months old so I do not think that is it.

Comment: You need to use VS11 x64 as target machine; that is where you are going wrong. If you just choose VS11, then 32-bit binaries are generated.

Comment: @scap3y, OP stated that he wants x86 binaries.

Comment: Yes, that was my point; I doubt it is possible to link against 2 different target libraries (x64 for CUDA and x86 for VC++); the only way I know how to make code cross platform is to use CMake to generate them to that particular machine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and ended up compiling it with VS2010. See if that works.